# Call to a member function where() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a website using CodeIgniter. When I open my page I get this error :

[image: CodeIngiter Error]

I haven't encountered this problem before, and know I have it in every controller that uses the database library.

This is an example of a function in a model where I get the error :

```
 public function login($pseudo,$password)
  {

    $this->db->where("pseudo",$pseudo);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);

    $query=$this->db->get("admin");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
      foreach($query->result() as $rows)
      {
        //add all data to session
        $newdata = array(
          'admin_id'  => $rows->id,
          'admin_pseudo'    => $rows->pseudo,
          'admin_fullname' => $rows->fullname,
          'admin_email' => $rows->email,
          'admin_logged_in'  => TRUE,
        );
      }
      $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

the line 13 is : `$this->db->where("pseudo",$pseudo);`

This is the controller :

```
public function login()
  {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'Pseudo', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $pseudo=$this->input->post('login'); 
    $password=md5($this->input->post('password'));


    $result=$this->admin_model->login($pseudo,$password);



    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
      if ($result) $this->dashboard();
      else        
        $this->index();
    }
  }
```

In the autoload file I have :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db` is not an object apparently. Check that it's properly initialized before calling `login()`

Answer (score 0):

- Can you actually connect to your database?
- Have you modified any configuration files that contain the database connection parameters?
- Have you modified the users of your database in any way?

Comment: Yes I can connect to my database, and I didn't modified the database connection parameters, I also didn't modified the users of my database